# How to block pre-commit using 100% of my CPU?

Tags: python, git, flake8, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have the pre-commit config file with pre-push hook type.
Every time when I push to the repo, my CPU shows me 100% of using power.

[image]

Why it happens? How can I set a border for max power?

**.pre-commit-config.yaml**

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8
        description: linter
        entry: flake8 --select=C812,WPS120,F401,WPS510 --config=setup.cfg server/apps/
        language: python
        types: [python]
```

Comment: Why do you not want to utilize your CPU? If it’s related to power consumption, maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291158/how-to-reduce-cpu-max-speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've misconfigured flake8 and so you are triggering a fork bomb (pre-commit's multiprocessing + flake8's multiprocessing) **and** you're double-linting every file in your codebase

I would recommend you utilize the official flake8 configuration rather than reimplementing your own (poorly):

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit and I'm the current flake8 maintainer